# Encrypt the data in a column of view (NOT TABLE) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a VIEW including join of different tables, I wanted to encrypt data of specific column with int data type. Is it necessary to create a TABLE from VIEW then run the encryption script or there is a solution to avoid doing this?

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY  PASSWORD = '1qaz!QAZ';
Go
CREATE CERTIFICATE Pay    WITH SUBJECT = 'PersonPyment';  
GO  
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY PayKeyMeritpay     WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256     ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE pay;  
GO  
ALTER TABLE  [dbo].[prs_vwDecreeItems]
   ADD Payment_Encrypted varbinary(128);  
GO  
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY PayKeyMeritpay  
  DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Pay;  

 
UPDATE [dbo].[prs_vwDecreeItems]
SET Payment_Encrypted = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('PayKeyMeritpay'), SumAmount, 1, HashBytes('shalgam', CONVERT( varbinary , PersonnelNo)));  
GO  

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY PayKeyMeritpay  
  DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Pay;  
GO  

SELECT
FirstName
,LastName
, PersonnelNo    AS 'Encrypted pay'
, CONVERT(nvarchar,DecryptByKey(Payment_Encrypted, 1 , HashBytes('shalgam', CONVERT(varbinary, PersonnelNo))))  AS 'Decrypted pay'
FROM   [dbo].[prs_vwDecreeItems]
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions :

- Create your view with the encryption of the needed columns
- Create an indexed view with the encryption of the needed columns, if possible

Comment: that's a great idea but problem is that the column of the view is SUM of the original tables amount.